# Livewire file upload can't accept .mp4 .exe files

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm encountering a problem with my Livewire file upload: it is not accepting .mp4 and .exe files. I'm also unable to retrieve the file size for a file located at: livewire-tmp/livewire-tmp.

```
use LivewireAlert;

public $driver;

public function update()
{
    $this->validate(['driver'=>'max:1024']);
    $this->driver->storeAs('public');
    $this->alert('success', 'Uploaded.', ['timerProgressBar' => true, 'width' => 'auto']);
    return ;
}
```

When I attempt to upload an image, the upload process proceeds as expected. However, it seems that Livewire may not support the upload of certain file types such as .exe, .sys, and .mp4.

**config/livewire.php**

```
'temporary_file_upload' => [
    'disk' => null,        // Example: 'local', 's3'              | Default: 'default'
    'rules' => null,       // Example: ['file', 'mimes:png,jpg']  | Default: ['required', 'file', 'max:12288'] (12MB)
    'directory' => null,   // Example: 'tmp'                      | Default: 'livewire-tmp'
    'middleware' => null,  // Example: 'throttle:5,1'             | Default: 'throttle:60,1'
    'preview_mimes' => [   // Supported file types for temporary pre-signed file URLs...
        'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg', 'wav', 'mp4',
        'mov', 'avi', 'wmv', 'mp3', 'm4a',
        'jpg', 'jpeg', 'mpga', 'webp', 'wma',
    ],
    'max_upload_time' => 5, // Max duration (in minutes) before an upload is invalidated...
],
```

I tried uploading the same files that failed to upload in Livewire, but this time in the Laravel controller (without Livewire), and it works.

Comment: Just to confirm, you said `.mp4.exe`, right? As in, a PE Executable program, i.e. untrusted executable code?

Comment: Yes but i want only to save it bot execute the program.